# Dirichlet Character Real Cyclic Cubic Field - Explicit Formula?

Tags: nt.number-theory

For a cyclotomic field of conductor $p$ with generating Dirichlet character $\chi$, we can explicitly compute the value $\chi(q) = (e^{2⋅\pi⋅i/(p−1)})^{n}$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes, $n$ is the smallest non-negative integer such that $z_{p}^{n} = q$ modulo $p$ and $z_{p}$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity. Consider a real cyclic cubic subfield of this cyclotomic field (hence of conductor also $p$ and necessarily with $p \equiv 1 \ mod \ 3$). How could one evaluate $\chi_{3}(q)$ via the same formula, where $\chi_{3}$ the generating character of this cubic field? Couldn't one see $\chi_{3}$ as a power of $\chi$? And if yes, how would one modify the formula above for computing $\chi_{3}(q)$?